# Google ad manager and AWS Elemental MediaTaylor comparison

Tags: google-ad-manager, aws-mediatailor

I am a newbie in this space. I have a requirement to dynamically insert an ad and setup the infrastructure to monetize it.
From some basic search, I see that Google ad manager and AWS Elemental MediaTaylor are major players.
I am looking for any platform that is easy to implement and show immediate value.
Looking for some pointers.
(Apologize if I have posted in the wrong forum).

Answer (score 1):

Off the bat, its worth keeping in mind that this space (i.e. the monetisation of 'Over The Top' content) is quite broad and can get technically deep very fast so some extensive research is recommended.

In terms of the two, you'll immediately notice that even though both offer dynamic ad insertions (DAI), both are not on the same level in terms of feature parity:

Google Ad Manager is an ad management platform for large publishers who have significant direct sales. Ad Manager provides granular controls and supports multiple ad exchanges and networks, including AdSense, Ad Exchange, third-party networks, and third-party exchanges.

Ad Manager is for you if you need:

A central place to monetize all of your inventory types (websites, mobile apps, videos, or games)
To manage a significant amount of ad revenue that comes through direct deals from buyers
To use third-party networks to compete for ad inventory
More complex reports to gain granular insights

[https://support.google.com/admanager/answer/6022000?hl=en#:~:text=Google%20Ad%20Manager%20is%20an,%2C%20and%20third%2Dparty%20exchanges](https://support.google.com/admanager/answer/6022000?hl=en#:%7E:text=Google%20Ad%20Manager%20is%20an,%2C%20and%20third%2Dparty%20exchanges).

AWS Elemental MediaTailor is a channel assembly and personalized ad insertion service for video providers to create linear OTT (internet delivered) channels using existing video content and monetize those channels, or other live streams and VOD content, with personalized advertising.

[https://aws.amazon.com/mediatailor/#:~:text=AWS%20Elemental%20MediaTailor%20is%20a,VOD%20content%2C%20with%20personalized%20advertising](https://aws.amazon.com/mediatailor/#:%7E:text=AWS%20Elemental%20MediaTailor%20is%20a,VOD%20content%2C%20with%20personalized%20advertising).

The above are key to keep in mind when establishing you present and future infrastructure requirements.

In terms of ease of implementation, since you mentioned being new to the space, both will require a learning curve when it comes to concepts / terminology as well as the respective content preparation + setup processes.
Perhaps consider reviewing the below resources to get an idea:

1. Getting started with Google Ad Manager’s Dynamic Ad Insertion : https://services.google.com/fh/files/misc/getting_started_with_dynamic_ad_insertion.pdf
2. Learn about Dynamic Ad Insertion (DAI) : https://support.google.com/admanager/answer/6147120?hl=en#zippy=%2Csee-how-the-dai-workflow-differs-from-traditional-video-ad-serving
3. Video on demand ad insertion with AWS Elemental MediaTailor : https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/media/video-on-demand-ad-insertion-with-aws-elemental-mediatailor/
4. How to implement reliable dynamic ad insertion using AWS Media Services : https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/media/how-to-implement-reliable-dynamic-ad-insertion-using-aws-media-services/